# Git rebase of cherry-picked commits that have been reverted can "lose" them

Tags: git, rebase

I've got this history:

```
          A---B---C---!BC
         /              \
    D---E---F---G--------H master
        \
         B'---C' new-branch
```

Commits `B` & `C` have been originally created in a feature branch at the top, then reverted in commit `!BC` and then the whole branch was merged to master. Commits `B'` and `C'` have been cherry-picked to a new-branch.

I'd now like to rebase `B'` and `C'` to master, so that the result looks like this:

```
          A---B---C---!BC
         /              \
    D---E---F---G--------H master
                          \
                           B'---C' new-branch
```

However, running `git rebase master` produces this:

```
          A---B---C---!BC 
         /              \
    D---E---F---G--------H master
                           new-branch
```

It's technically correct as git-rebase docs state [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description):

> a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped

However, from a human perspective, this isn't right – my working directory is missing changes from `B` and `C`.

How do I run `git rebase` so that it produces the "expected" history?

Answer (score 2):

The [`--force-rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---force-rebase) flag does it:

```
git rebase --force-rebase master
```

See also [git - cherry-picked feature commits into new branch, reverted commits, rebase not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461088/git-cherry-picked-feature-commits-into-new-branch-reverted-commits-rebase-no).